# UFT showing some popup error's while running the scripts

Tags: testing, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft, guidance-automation-tool

Am using descriptive programming, while running the scripts in some playback UFT showing some error popup message. So we need to manually handle that uft window and after that script playback starts. Is there any solution to avoid this poop up messages? Attaching snap shotsof UFT error popup's

Comment: There is no snap-shot attached. Please provide an example somewhere of what you are describing..

Comment: Stackoverflow not giving me permission to upload snap shots. I have snap shots of 3 different error popup's of UFT but how come i share that..... :(

Comment: In edit mode click `ctrl+G`, it should let you add the screenshot.

Comment: Just quoting the popup error message would be useful

Answer (score 0):

You can disable popUp error messages by :
**File->Settings-> Run** and set the "When error occurs during run session " to "**proceed to next step**".
I hope this answer your question